# Using one gsub command to replace different dates with other dates

Tags: r, gsub

I have a quite large dataset with about 200000 rows and 15 columns among which there is a column "Date" in this format "1/18/1996 0:00:00" and I have different dates from 1996 until 2011 with the same format:

```
head(data$Date)
[1] "1/6/1996 0:00:00"  "1/11/1996 0:00:00" "1/11/1996 0:00:00" "1/11/1996 0:00:00"
[5] "1/11/1996 0:00:00" "1/18/1996 0:00:00"
```

I would like to replace those date with only the year "1996, 1997, ..., 2011"; I could do that with several gsub command like this:

```
x<- gsub(".*/1996 .*", "1996", data$Date)
```

and it works fine for substitution, but I would like to have only one command for that and add a new command to my dataset containing only the years, is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should use datetime functions instead of regex for tasks like this:

```
Date <- c("1/6/1996 0:00:00", "1/11/1996 0:00:00", "1/11/1996 0:00:00",
          "1/11/1996 0:00:00", "1/11/1996 0:00:00", "1/18/1996 0:00:00")

Date <- as.POSIXct(Date, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")
as.POSIXlt(Date)$year + 1900
#[1] 1996 1996 1996 1996 1996 1996
```

Comment: Thanks Roland, very straightforward way :-) You are right using datetime functions is easier!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
Date <- c("1/6/1996 0:00:00", "1/11/1996 0:00:00", "1/11/1996 0:00:00",
          "1/11/1996 0:00:00", "1/11/1996 0:00:00", "1/18/1996 0:00:00")

gsub("(.+/){2}| .+", "", Date)
# [1] "1996" "1996" "1996" "1996" "1996" "1996"
```

Comment: Sven, thanks, it worked fine :-))... I was struggling using gsubfn...but it seems your way is great! I have to search more to figure out how these meta-characters work?

Answer (score 0):

`data$Date.new <- sub(".*/(\\d{4}).*", "\\1", data$Date)`?

Answer (score 0):

Using `lubridate` and @Sven data, It is easier to convert strings to dates using built-in functions like `mdy_hms`:

```
mdy_hms(Dates)

"1996-01-06 UTC" "1996-01-11 UTC" "1996-01-11 UTC" 
"1996-01-11 UTC" "1996-01-11 UTC" "1996-01-18 UTC"
```

To get  years , one can apply `year` function:

```
year(mdy_hms(Dates))
 1996 1996 1996 1996 1996 1996
```